# A question about reduced torsion abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups

If a reduced torsion abelian group has no cyclic direct summands of order greater than 2, is it an elementary abelian 2-group?

**Background:**  I'm trying to classify the groups whose group rings have a certain property related to a class of rings that I'm studying.  It can be shown that no group with a cyclic direct summand of order greater than 2 has this property.  I'd like to conclude that the only reduced torsion abelian groups with this property are the elementary abelian 2-groups.  I know from Kaplansky's book that every reduced torsion abelian group has a finite cyclic direct summand (Theorem 9).  I'm having trouble getting from there to the conclusion I'd like.

Comment: Yes; the key is Lemma 65.4 in Fuchs's "Infinite Abelian Groups", volume II (which basically shows every element has order 2).