# A question about reduced p-groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I need help with an exercise from Kaplansky's *Infinite Abelian Groups* (Section 9, Exercise 27).  He states the problem as follows:

> Let $G$ be a reduced primary group
>   which is not of bounded order.  Prove
>   that $G$ has cyclic direct summands of
>   arbitrarily high order.

This also is an exercise in Fuchs' *Infinite Abelian Groups* ([Section 27, Exercise 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vb38GspKia8C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=%22cyclic%20direct%20summands%20of%20arbitrarily%20high%20orders%22&f=false)).

Comment: See also the similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47115/a-question-about-reduced-torsion-abelian-groups

Comment: I've merged your accounts (by the way, flagging a post for moderator attention is indeed the right way of going about it).

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be such a group, and let $B_i = \{a\in A\ |\ |a|=p\text{ and } h(a)=i\}$.  Note that at least one of the $B_i$ is non-empty by Lemma 8 in section 9.  Also, if there existed an $N$ such that for all $m>N$, $B_m$ was empty, then for all $a\in A$, we would have $p^{N+1}a=0$, so $A$ would have bounded order.  Thus infinitely many of the $B_i$ are non-empty; now simply mimic the proof of Theorem 9, using Lemma 7 and Theorem 7.

**EDIT** - Sorry, I left out a couple details, which I don't mind filling in.  First, $h(a)$ means the *height* of $a$.  Second, if such an $N$ existed as above, then every element of order $p$ in $p^{N+1}A$ would have infinite height in $A$.  It is easy to see this implies it has infinite height in $p^{N+1}A$.  Thus $p^{N+1}A$ is divisible; since $A$ is reduced, it is $0$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick answer!